# JPanel is not showing in the tab paned

Tags: java, jlabel

I am facing this issue the Gui is not showing the jlabel while i have checked all the things here
First we have tabbed pane
In tabbed pane we have scroll pane
In scroll Pane we have simple pane
In simple pane we have a label

```
 JScrollPane j1=new JScrollPane();
    
       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       panel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());
       JLabel j2=new JLabel();
       j2.setVisible(true);
       panel.add(j2, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());
       j1.setViewportView(panel);
       String name="panel "+count;
       count++;
       jTabbedPane1.addTab(name,j1);
```

can anyone figure out why jlabel is not showing while the code is working fine in the drag and drop

Comment: A [mcve] might be useful

Comment: Your JLabel (`j2`) does not have any text, so it is no surprise, you cannot see it. If you're talking about a different label, please specify.

Comment: the answer above is literally it.

Comment: In addition to the label having no text, the empty GridBagConstrains is also not something you'll really want to do - and GridBagLayout is complicated anyway. Try a FlowLayout or BorderLayout. Also, j2.setVisible(true) is not necessary.